# Две mainActivity api 28

Tags: android, android-studio

*Столкнулся с проблемой когда запускается две Activity на телефонах >api 22
Ниже api 22 все идеально работает и запускается только одна Activity*

Из-за этого у меня работает два потока а мне это собственно не нужно. Решение я уже нашел, но мне бы обосновать почему на api 28 так происходит

Логи:

```
06-14 14:51:36.635 6697-6697/comdevfromsakuraso.vk.ccsg I/123: oNcreate activity
06-14 14:51:36.667 6697-6754/comdevfromsakuraso.vk.ccsg I/123: Thread
06-14 14:51:36.670 6697-6697/comdevfromsakuraso.vk.ccsg I/123: Start Activity
06-14 14:51:38.134 6697-6697/comdevfromsakuraso.vk.ccsg I/123: Pause Activity
06-14 14:51:38.140 6697-6697/comdevfromsakuraso.vk.ccsg I/123: Destroy Activity
06-14 14:51:38.162 6697-6697/comdevfromsakuraso.vk.ccsg I/123: oNcreate activity
06-14 14:51:38.181 6697-6756/comdevfromsakuraso.vk.ccsg I/123: Thread
06-14 14:51:38.184 6697-6697/comdevfromsakuraso.vk.ccsg I/123: Start Activity
06-14 14:51:41.668 6697-6754/comdevfromsakuraso.vk.ccsg I/123: Thread
06-14 14:51:43.183 6697-6756/comdevfromsakuraso.vk.ccsg I/123: Thread
06-14 14:51:46.671 6697-6754/comdevfromsakuraso.vk.ccsg I/123: Thread
06-14 14:51:48.185 6697-6756/comdevfromsakuraso.vk.ccsg I/123: Thread
06-14 14:51:51.673 6697-6754/comdevfromsakuraso.vk.ccsg I/123: Thread
06-14 14:51:53.187 6697-6756/comdevfromsakuraso.vk.ccsg I/123: Thread
```

Comment: решил проблему способом переопределения метода onDestroy чтобы он отрубал поток (Кому надо)

Comment: Фоновый поток не привязан к жизненному циклу `Activity`. Об его остановке, когда он больше не нужен, но ещё не завершился Вы должны позаботиться сами. А вот почему у Вас `Activity` перезапускается сразу после старта непонятно. Нужно видеть код и при каких условиях это происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вызов onDestroy не гарантирован, может происходить уже тогда когда не хватает памяти https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#ondestroy. Без понимания логики что делает тред трудно дать совет, тем не менее лучше останавливать в onStop, или делать явно finish(). Также посмотрите на флаги активити в манифесте.